# Check for hidden div that exists in the dom in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
if ($('.result-all').length>0) {               
    if ($('.result-all').is(':hidden')) {     
        //execute code
    }
}
```

I have div that has class `.result-all`. I want to check if it exists in the dom but also if it's hidden (I want to some updates on other divs when it's hidden), but I don't why it doesn't get to the point "execute code" (above)

For some reason it doesn't "indicates" as hidden, even though I've used `fadeOut()` on the div with class `.result-all` before. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I'm not doing any fadeOut in conjunction with this check. This check is done when a link is clicked.

Comment: Can you show it in a JSfiddle?

Comment: how is the element hidden?

Comment: if you are executing this code soon after `fadeOut` it won't work, you need to do it in the `fadeOut` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
if ($(".result-all:hidden").length > 0) {               
    //execute code
}
```

Update -
Sharing a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/E59Ap/2/)

Comment: Thank you. This got me on the right track. I see now that is wasn't the actual .result-all that was hidden, but some divs inside it. so therefore it didn't work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When using [`$.fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) you need to perform checks in callback, as you have to wait for them to take effect.

```
fadeOut(100, function(){
    if ($('.result-all').length>0) {               
        if ($('.result-all').is(':hidden')) {     
            //execute code
        }
    }
})
```